# Can not access jar file under lib folder in apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have put my jar files in folder named "myLibs" under lib folder of my application. When I run application I get `NoClassDefFoundException` for the classes which are inside the jars (placed inside myLibs folder). But when I put that inside lib folder I can access it's classes. So my question is: *"Can't we create a folder inside lib folder of our application in apache tomcat and put over jars there? Why is this not possible?"*

My folder structure:-

```
TOMCAT_HOME
|
+----webapps
     |
     +---- MyApp
           |
           +----WEB_INF
                |
                +----lib
                     |
                     +----myLibs
```

Apache tomcat version:- 6.0.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to adjust your `$CLASSPATH` to include the path `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/MyApp/WEB_INF/lib/myLibs`. You might specify it in `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat takes the default directory as lib......so if you want to hmake your own folder inside the lib then u probably need to redefine the the path.....
[look here for more details](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)
hope it helps....